# Why Isn't ray collisions working in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I was working through this tutorial. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBtaLCmJexk 
and I can't find the error in my code anywhere
The problem is just that after working on the vertical ray collisions I run the program and the block just falls through the obstacle. 
here is the player code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Controller2D))]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    float gravity = -20;
    Vector3 velocity;

    Controller2D controller;

    void Start() {
        controller = GetComponent<Controller2D>();
    }

    void Update() {
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

and here is the Controller2D code:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]
public class Controller2D : MonoBehaviour {
    public LayerMask collisionMask;
    const float skinWidth = .015f;
    public int horizontalRayCount = 4;
    public int verticalRayCount = 4;

    float horizontalRaySpacing;
    float verticalRaySpacing;

    BoxCollider2D collider;
    RaycastOrigins raycastOrigins;

    void Start() {
        collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        CalculateRaySpacing();
    }

    public void Move(Vector3 velocity) {
        UpdateRaycastOrigins();
        VerticalCollisions(ref velocity);
        transform.Translate(velocity);
    }

    void VerticalCollisions(ref Vector3 velocity) {
        float directionY = Mathf.Sign(velocity.y);
        float rayLength = Mathf.Abs(velocity.y) + skinWidth;
        for (int i = 0; i < verticalRayCount; i++) {
            Vector2 rayOrigin = (directionY == -1) ? raycastOrigins.bottomLeft : raycastOrigins.topLeft;
            rayOrigin += Vector2.right * (verticalRaySpacing * i + velocity.x);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOrigin, Vector2.up * directionY, rayLength, collisionMask);
            Debug.DrawRay(raycastOrigins.bottomLeft + Vector2.right * verticalRaySpacing * i, Vector2.up * -2, Color.red);
            if (hit) {
                velocity.y = (hit.distance - skinWidth) * directionY;
                rayLength = hit.distance;
            }
        }
    }

    void UpdateRaycastOrigins() {
        Bounds bounds = collider.bounds;
        bounds.Expand(skinWidth * -2);

        raycastOrigins.bottomLeft = new Vector2(bounds.min.x, bounds.min.y);
        raycastOrigins.bottomRight = new Vector2(bounds.max.x, bounds.min.y);
        raycastOrigins.topLeft = new Vector2(bounds.min.x, bounds.max.y);
        raycastOrigins.topRight = new Vector2(bounds.max.x, bounds.max.y);
    }

    void CalculateRaySpacing() {
        Bounds bounds = collider.bounds;
        bounds.Expand(skinWidth * -2);

        horizontalRayCount = Mathf.Clamp(horizontalRayCount, 2, int.MaxValue);
        verticalRayCount = Mathf.Clamp(verticalRayCount, 2, int.MaxValue);

        horizontalRaySpacing = bounds.size.y / (horizontalRayCount - 1);
        verticalRaySpacing = bounds.size.y / (verticalRayCount - 1);
    }

    struct RaycastOrigins {
        public Vector2 topLeft, topRight;
        public Vector2 bottomLeft, bottomRight;
    }
}
```

Edit: The code is (as I understand from a half an hour tutorial.) just defining attributes to a quad(player) so that it can collide with another quad(obstacle). at the moment the code should only work vertically. so I am testing it by drawing the obstacle under the player and pressing play. the player should come to rest on the obstacle but instead, it sinks straight through it. 
[My screen after selecting the player block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K3LR.png)

and asking about debugging, I dont understand the language well enough to not break anything while trying to debug it.

Comment: @JordanYoung - Please post if you have done any debugging and if you did find anything, Also, what is the expected outcome of the code and how does it differ from the real outcome.

Comment: @ShaktiPrakashSingh I have added an edit at the bottom of the post, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I just got someone on discord to help and it turns out I didn't have the obstacle set with boxcollider2D
Many Thanks all who tried.